# Tensorflow very low accuracy on validation set

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am building a tensorflow model to classify images to different dog breeds, using the "stanford_dogs" dataset which can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/stanford_dogs)

This is how I am creating a dataset

```
url = 'http://vision.stanford.edu/aditya86/ImageNetDogs/images.tar'

dataset = tf.keras.utils.get_file("Images", url, untar=True, cache_dir='.', cache_subdir='')
dataset_path = pathlib.Path(dataset)
image_count = len(list(dataset_path.glob('*/*.jpg')))

total_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(dataset_path/'*/*'), shuffle = False)
total_ds = total_ds.shuffle(image_count, reshuffle_each_iteration = False)

class_names = np.array(sorted([item.name for item in dataset_path.glob('*') if item.name != "LICENSE.txt"]))

val_size = int(image_count * 0.2)
train_ds = total_ds.skip(val_size) #Training Set
val_ds   = total_ds.take(val_size) #Validation Set

batch_size = 32
img_height = 180
img_width = 180

def get_label(file_path):
  # convert the path to a list of path components
  parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
  # The second to last is the class-directory
  one_hot = parts[-2] == class_names
  # Integer encode the label
  return tf.argmax(one_hot)

def decode_img(img):
    # convert the compressed string to a 3D uint8 tensor
    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
    # resize the image to the desired size
    return tf.image.resize(img, [img_height, img_width])

def process_path(file_path):
     label = get_label(file_path)
     # load the raw data from the file as a string
     img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
     img = decode_img(img)
     return img, label

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

train_ds = train_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
```

After that i am doing the following

```
 normalization_layer = layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255)

 def configure_for_performance(ds):
     ds = ds.cache()
     ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
     ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
     ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
     ds = ds.map(lambda x,y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
     return ds

 train_ds = configure_for_performance(train_ds)
 val_ds = configure_for_performance(val_ds)
```

After that I compile and train the model as shown below

```
  num_classes = 120

  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='sigmoid'),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.Dense(num_classes)
  ]) 

  model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
          metrics=['accuracy'])

  epochs=20
  history = model.fit(
       train_ds,
       validation_data=val_ds,
       epochs=epochs
       )
```

After training I get high training accuracy (aroung 94-95%) but the validation accuracy I get is very low (around 8-10%).

What am I doing wrong, I searched online and some say that the dataset should be shuffled before splitting the data, but I already did that. I am stuck here, I tried changing the activation, the number of neurons, number of hidden layers...but no luck.

Also, if I add regularization then both accuracies are dropping to around 10% (Added regularization with 4 hidden layers with 512 neurons in each layer).

Would be very helpful if someone could explain to me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `sigmoid` activations in intermediate layers do not make any sense

Comment: @desertnaut I tried changing the activation to relu too. Same thing

Comment: Your layer activations are all nonsense, especially considering you are using linear activation in your final layer. I suggest first reading up on how these activations, as well as the loss function you are using, work in the Keras documentation.

Comment: I don't get exactly where the 'nonsense' is although it might not be the best solution. I've also seen this on some occasions on models that performs pretty well but I can't figure out why I got the low validation performance either.